# Derivative of a function as an exponent

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm trying to find the derivative of $x^{f(x)}$.  I've tried a number of methods, the most successful of which (I think) was $2x^{f(x)+1}\cdot\ln{x}\cdot f'(x)$.  Graphing this for a few different functions for $f(x)$ shows that I'm incorrect, and I'm a bit stuck. How should I go about solving this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arbitrary exponents only make sense for positive numbers. By definition, 
$$
x^{f(x)}=e^{f(x)\,\ln x}.
$$
Using the chain rule and the product rule, the derivative is 
$$
(e^{f(x)\,\ln x})\, (f(x)\ln x)'=e^{f(x)\,\ln x}(f'(x)\ln x+\tfrac{f(x)}x)
=x^{f(x)}\,(f'(x)\ln x+\tfrac{f(x)}x).
$$
Factoring the $1/x$ out you may write 
$$
(x^{f(x)})'=x^{f(x)-1}(xf'(x)\,\ln x+f(x))
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$
\left(x^{f(x)}\right)'=\left(e^{\ln{x^{f(x)}}}\right)'=\left(e^{f(x)\cdot\ln{x}}\right)'=e^{f(x)\cdot\ln{x}}\cdot\left(f(x)\cdot\ln{x}\right)'.
$$

Answer (score 1):

The formula to know (which is not often taught in basic calculus) is:
$$d(x^y) = yx^{y - 1}\,dx + \ln(x)\, x^y\,dy$$
Note that it is a combination of the power rule (left) and the exponential rule (right).

There are two ways of deriving this formula.  The first is to note that a total differential is merely the sum of its partials.  That is, if $u$ is a function of $x$ and $y$, $du = \partial x + \partial y$.  In this case, $u = x^y$, so one partial will be the power rule, and the other partial will be the exponential rule.

For an explicit derivation, let's start by saying $u = x^y$.  We can get rid of the exponential by taking the logarithm of both sides.  Therefore $$\ln(u) = \ln(x^y) \\ \ln(u) = y\,\ln(x) $$

Now we can differentiate both sides:

$$d(\ln(u)) = d(y\,\ln(x)) \\
\frac{1}{u}\,du = y\, \frac{1}{x}\,dx + \ln(x)\,dy \\
$$
Solving for $du$ yields:
$$du = \frac{yu}{x}\,dx + \ln(x)\,u\,dy$$
Now, we know from our original equation $u = x^y$ that we can replace $u$ with $x^y$.  Therefore:
$$du = \frac{y\,x^y}{x}\,dx + \ln(x)\,x^y\,dy$$
Now, $\frac{x^y}{x}$ is the same as $x^{y-1}$.  This substitution yields:
$$du = y\,x^{y-1}\,dx + \ln(x)\,x^y\,dy$$
Since $du = d(x^y)$, that becomes:
$$d(x^y) = y\,x^{y-1}\,dx + \ln(x)\,x^y\,dy$$
This is the given formula!

Comment: How did you derive that formula?

Comment: There are two ways to derive it.  The first is that a total derivative is merely the sum of its partials.  The partial of x (holding y const) is the power rule, and the partial of y (holding x const) is the exponential rule, therefore, adding them together will give you the total derivative.

Comment: Alternatively, just do logarithmic differentiation.  Say $z = x^y$.  Therefore $\ln(z) = y\ln(x)$.  Differentiating both sides yields $\frac{dz}{z} = \frac{y}{x}dx + \ln(x) dy$.  Multiplying both sides by $z$ yields $dz = \frac{y}{x} z\,dx + \ln(x)z\, dy$.  Remember that $z = x^y$ yields $dz = \frac{y}{x} x^y dx + \ln(x) x^y dy$.  $x^y/x$ = $x^{y-1}$, so this simplifies to $dz = y x^{y - 1} dx + \ln(x)\,x^y\,dy$.

Comment: Most calculus texts teach logarithmic differentiation, but never teach the rule.  With the rule, you actually *never* need logarithmic differentiation (with some exception for products of sequences), and can just use the rule.  I included the rule itself in "Calculus from the Ground Up" because I think it is super-useful, both as a tool for dealing with exponentiation, and as a nice example for showing how partial differentials can combine into a total differential.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments and the derivation. I really made that comment so that you would include the derivation in your answer (so, another user scanning these answers would see it).

Comment: @Axion004 - thanks! - I modified the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Take log and differentiate like implicit function.

Let  y = x^f(x) ; then ln(y)=f(x). ln(x)
Now differentiate.  I.e ( dy/dx)/y = (f(x)/x) +( d(f(x))/dx)*ln(x)
dy/dx = ( x^ f(x)).(( f(x)/x) + f'(x)*ln(x))

Comment: Do you know MathJax or Latex? Please write your answer in formatted equations.

Comment: Sorry I do not have Idea of MathJax do I need to download the app or how can I start on it kindly help on this matter.